# Domain Driven Design : Can aggregate root have public setter?

Tags: design-patterns, repository, domain-driven-design

If I have a aggregate root says **User** It have property like

```
public class User:BaseEntity
{


    public User()
    {
        //Ef Use
    }

    public User(string firstName, string secondName,
        string userName,Password password )
    {
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.Password = password;
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.SecondName = secondName;
    }

    public string UserName { get; private set;}
    public Password Password { get; private set;}
    public string FirstName { get; private set;}
    public string SecondName { get; private set;}
}
```

I can create new user like `var naz=new User ("naz","password","firstName","secondname"`)
 and save using `UserRepository` .
How should I edit User `fistname` property ?
Should I need to make public setter and Save using repository ? .
I am confused ,new to DDD .How Should I implement this .

Comment: DDD is not about technical (tactical) patterns like the Repository. It's about modeling your domain the way it is. We can't tell how your aggregate roots should be designed without knowing your domain, but you seem to have it wrong. ARs aren't property buckets and DDD is not well suited for CRUD. Use an ActiveRecord approach if that's what you need and don't just try to apply DDD because you thought it looked cool because you will fail if you do not understand the core strategic patterns.

Comment: Totally agree with @plalx,
I can just add that the good question should be, what is the business needs for changing a first name (without knowing the Domain, I see that like no sense a User change name maybe only for correcting in majority of cases). In general we will prefere an explicit method for updating value (like when you change adresses you don't set value, you have method called move location or something ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain Entities carries state and you will generally will need to be able to change this state. If you are using a DDD approach your above example my look something like this.

1. Call update name method on application layer providing id and new name.
2. Application layer gets the user domain model via the repository.
3. You can then either call update name method on your user entity or just set it via a setter.
4. You then save your entity. Typically you might use an ORM that tracks object changes and in that case you will just call save on your repo from your application layer.

Your example is not a good DDD example though as your user domain model is basically just a DTO.

Answer (score 0):

Update username can be done via calling a method like this:

```
public void ChangeUsername(string newName)
{
 //Check any required business rules.
 this.UserName = newName;
}
```

A point that you gain, is you can check any business rules that related to changing username.

Although Ubiquitous-Language will be more explicit with this approach.